# How to secure plist or NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Can these files be easily encrypted to prevent users (with jailbroken iPhones) from modifying values?

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is the Keychain api. Other apps on jailbroken devices can get TO your keychain values, but they're encrypted.

[Here's a decent tutorial I just googled up.](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html)

Comment: Would it not be a frowned upon practice to store xml objects in the keychain?

Comment: Who said anything about xml objects? Take the data content itself and put it in the keychain.

Comment: That wasn't really my point.  Would it not be a bad practice to store anything other than simple strings/passwords in the keychain?

Comment: Well, look, it's an encrypted plist, is all it is. As long as it's plistable data, it's fair game.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Secure-NSUserDefaults, it is a good way to prevent you plists from being changed.

You can get the code at: https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults

Good luck!